# Is the no public IP address feature for Databricks in GA?

Tags: azure-databricks

Is the feature enabled via the ARM template option enableNoPublicIP currently in general availability. The webinar https://databricks.com/p/webinar/azure-databricks-security-best-practices suggests this was in a private preview a while ago. I need to use this feature to be able to comply with the requirements for a client, but they also have a requirement that no feature in preview are used.

Answer (score 2):

> Currently, no-public IP is in **public preview**.

With secure cluster connectivity enabled, customer virtual networks have no open ports and Databricks Runtime cluster nodes have no public IP addresses.

**Documentation:** [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secure-cluster-connectivity](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secure-cluster-connectivity)

---

Have you tried this [template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.databricks/workspaces) to enableNoPublicIP?

To create a Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces resource, add the following JSON to the resources section of your template.

```
{
            'type': 'Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces',
            'apiVersion': '2018-04-01',
            'name': '[parameters('workspaceName')]',
            'location': '[parameters('location')]',
            'dependsOn': [],
            'tags': {
                'data platform': 'warehouse'
            },
            'sku': {
                'name': 'standard'
            },
            'properties': {
                'ManagedResourceGroupId': '[variables('managedResourceGroupId')]',
                'parameters': {
                    'enableNoPublicIp': {
                        'value': true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

In case, if you are receiving the below error message for the deployment, you need to create a support to ticket.

```
{
    'status': 'Failed',
    'error': {
        'code': 'ResourceDeploymentFailure',
        'message': 'The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.',
        'details': [
            {
                'code': 'CustomerUnauthorized',
                'message': 'CUSTOMER_UNAUTHORIZED: Subscription: XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX Is Not Authorized to Create No Public IP Workspaces.'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Once you create the support ticket, backend team will help you to enable the `enableNoPublicIp` for your subscription.

Comment: This is the feature I am asking about, My question was is this still only available via private preview, and if so when is it likely to be GA?

Comment: @JohnNunn Exited to share that no-public IP is now in public preview. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: @cheekatalapradeep-msft thanks for the update, this will help to make my client happier. Is there any roadmap and date planned for GA?